# What kind of liquid propulsion systems do GEO satellites use?

Tags: artificial-satellite, propulsion, orbit, geostationary

Coming from a question about [distances between satellites in GEO](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/2515/how-closely-spaced-are-satellites-at-geo), what liquid propulsion systems do a majority of GEO satellites carry to maintain their slot positions? It is easy to find information about Merlin engines, SSME, Rocketdyne F-1, etc., but smaller purpose engines are harder to find.

**UPDATE**

Thanks for the info about the propellents used. What about the engines?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Typically GEO satellites use either mono-prop (often hydrazine) or bi-prop (often Mono Methyl Hydrazine and Nitrogen Tetroxide) storable propellant engines for station keeping.  Electric propulsion is a technology that is also used for GEO spacecraft station keeping (http://spaceflightnow.com/news/n1203/19boeing702sp/).

Answer (score 1):

Some examples of small engines:
[Northrop Grumman](http://www.northropgrumman.com/Capabilities/PropulsionProductsandServices/Pages/default.aspx) [Bipropellant thrusters](http://www.northropgrumman.com/Capabilities/PropulsionProductsandServices/Pages/BipropellantEnginesAndThrusters.aspx):

> ```
> -TR-308 Liquid Apogee Engine, which placed the NASA Chandra X-ray Observatory spacecraft into its final orbit. The Liquid Apogee Engine (LAE) is the world's highest performing apogee engine.
> -TR-312 Liquid Apogee Engines (TR-312-100MN and TR-312-100YN) which have completed DVT testing for commerical geostationary comsat applications.
> -TR-500 Secondary Combustion Augmented Thruster (SCAT) Bi-Modal Thruster, flight-proven on the National Reconnaissance Office's Geosynchronous Lightweight Technology Experiment (GeoLITE) program.
> -TR-711 Gel Boost Engine, which powered the world's first flight of a tactical missile utilizing gelled propellants and achieved a 700:1 Thurst-to-Weight Ratio.
> -LOX/LH2 and LOX/Ethanol RCS engines successfully test fired in 1000 lbf and 870 lbf configurations, respectively.
> -NASA RCE contract for a 100 lbf class LOX/Methane.
> ```

[Monopropellant thrusters](http://www.northropgrumman.com/Capabilities/PropulsionProductsandServices/Pages/MonopropellantThrusters.aspx) - several models between 1 and 86 N, using hydrazine.

Aerojet Rocketdyne:
[Monopropellant thrusters](https://www.rocket.com/propulsion-systems/monopropellant-rockets), hydrazine, 1-3100 N.
[Biprop thrusters](https://www.rocket.com/propulsion-systems/bipropellant-rockets), MMH/NTO or Hydrazine (N$_2$H$_4$)/NTO, 22 N-4 kN.

[EADS Astrium](http://cs.astrium.eads.net/sp/spacecraft-propulsion/propulsion-systems/index.html):
[bipropellant thrusters](http://cs.astrium.eads.net/sp/spacecraft-propulsion/bipropellant-thrusters/index.html) 4-200 N, MMH and N$_2$O$_4$ or mixed oxides of nitrogen (MON)
[hydrazine thrusters](http://cs.astrium.eads.net/sp/spacecraft-propulsion/hydrazine-thrusters/index.html) 1-400 N
[Apogee engines](http://cs.astrium.eads.net/sp/spacecraft-propulsion/apogee-motors/index.html), MMH and N$_2$O$_4$ or mixed oxides of nitrogen (MON)
[ion engines](http://cs.astrium.eads.net/sp/spacecraft-propulsion/ion-propulsion/index.html), thrust 50 $\mu$N to 200 mN

Answer (score 0):

Try this link for a few small thruster types. Its out of date, the names of manufacturers have changed since this list but the thruster names are probably still in use. 
https://engineering.purdue.edu/~propulsi/propulsion/rockets/satellites.html

Comment: This is essentially a _link only answer_, so it might become obsolete if the link changes or becomes unavailable. Please [edit] to include essential information required to answer the question here. Thanks!

Comment: TRW is now part of Northrop Grumman, most of the others ended up in Aerojet Rocketdyne.

Comment: OK, I understand, thanks for the reminder. I think Hobbes' answer covers it quite well.