# What are the space-based optical satellite sensors?

Tags: artificial-satellite, tracking, optical

I was looking at a products page for [Numerica Corp](https://www.numerica.us/defense/space-situational-awareness/#mfast), and under their product MFAST it said (emphasis mine):

> Tracks objects in all regimes of space (e.g., LEO, MEO, HEO, GEO) using radar, ground-based optical, and *space-based optical sensors*.

This is my first time hearing of a space-based optical system to track satellites.  What system(s) would this be?

Comment: They are reffering to the [spherical cow-sat](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/19385/12102)

Comment: @uhoh, but what is observing those cows from space?

Comment: Good point! I don't know, but I am afraid that some of them may not be herbivores.

Comment: From what I've understood, this company provides ground-based optical (and radar) systems, which are aimed at space assets to track their orbits. The goal of this is to ensure that debris and dead spacecraft do not collide against operational satellites.